# How can I use cargo build scripts to create a binary

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to create a binary from a rust within a rust build script.

I tried to create a file `OUT_DIR/bin/hello_from_build_script_binary` like this:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = env::var_os("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    fs::create_dir_all(format!("{}/bin", out_dir)).unwrap();
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir)
        .join("bin")
        .join("hello_from_build_script_binary.rs");
    fs::write(
        &dest_path,
        "pub fn main() -> &'static str {
            \"Hello from my build script binary!\"
        }
        ",
    )
    .unwrap();
}
```

And running it like:

```bash
$ cargo run --bin hello_from_build_script_binary
```

which gave me the error

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `#########/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  can't find `bar` bin at `src/bin/bello_from_build_script_binary.rs` or `src/bin/bello_from_build_script_binary/main.rs`. Please specify bin.path if you want to use a non-default path.
```

I also tried putting the binary in `OUT_DIR/.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the top-level file can't be generated by `build.rs` and must exist in your `src` or `src/bin` folder. But you can have a file named `hello_from_build_script_binary.rs` in `src/bin` with just this content:

```
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/bin/hello_from_build_script_binary.rs"));
```

so that it will include the contents of the generated file, and have the real code generated by `build.rs` like you're already doing.

Comment: I think you are correct, the answer seems do be "You can't". But do you have a link where this is documented? Having the binary source files exist before compilation does not work for my use case unfortunately.